# how to get account details when integrating plaid api

Tags: javascript, ruby, api, coffeescript, plaid

I am actually trying to integrate Plaid api for ACH payments and following "https://plaid.com/docs/link/" tutorial in Ruby. In this I have written the js code and it shows me pop up to select bank accounts. 
I am using it in sandbox mode in which I am using test credentials to verify the account and it successfully verifies the account. For server side scripting I have installed `plaid` gem and configured it using following code into my_app/config/initializers/plaid.rb

```
Plaid.config do |p|
  p.customer_id = 'test_id'
  p.secret = 'test_secret'
  p.environment_location = 'https://tartan.plaid.com'
end
```

where I have replaced the customer_id and secret key with my own. I am using a user controller in which under create method I am trying to create a user like this:

```
user = Plaid.add_user('auth', 'plaid_test', 'plaid_good', 'usaa', '1234')
```

Now I am confused how would it work.
I am trying to create a server side handler using ruby but I dont understand where I am lacking (as I am new to Ruby). I actually want that after successfully validating credentials there should be an option to select account like in the given demo
https://demo.plaid.com/stripe

I really need help as I am badly stuck in this from last three days. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plaid Link returns a 'public_token' - you'll need to use the [/exchange_token API endpoint](https://plaid.com/docs/link/#-exchange_token-endpoint) to exchange the public token for an API access token.

The plaid-ruby library has a [detailed example](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-ruby#exchanging-a-link-public_token-for-a-plaid-access_token) of the exchange token flow!